# ggplot2 stat_function() not ploting the exact area under curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to graph the area under t distribution tail, like in [this example](https://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/03/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-9-function-plots.html#:%7E:text=Basic%20normal%20curve%20In%20order%20to%20create%20a,function%20argument%20to%20make%20it%20a%20normal%20curve.) but, for some degrees of freedom it is not drawing the area I want. The vertical line marks the lower t critical value so I expect `geom_area` to shade upto the line. For instance I have tried this with 4,9,99 and 999 degrees of freedom but only 4 and 999 df worked, see the attached images:

[image: 4 df]

[image: 9 df]

[image: 99 df]

[image: 999 df]

Here is the code.

```
alpha=0.1
n=5

l.critical = qt(alpha,df=n-1)
u.critical = -l.critical


# function to shade lower tail
funcShaded <- function(x) {
  y <- dt(x,df=n-1)
  y[x>l.critical]<-NA
  return(y)
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(l.critical-3,u.critical+3)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dt,
                args = list(df=n-1),linewidth=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "t values")+
  stat_function(fun=funcShaded, geom="area", fill="#84CA72", alpha=1,
                outline.type="full",color="black")+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())+
  labs(y="")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=l.critical)
```

I suspect the problem might be the line  `y[x>l.critical]<-NA` where I replace the y values above my lower critical value i.e the **Upper  tail** with NA, because probably the x values generated by stat_function() doesn't include my lower critical value, this would lead to a situation where the highest value not replaced is for x less than the lower critical value, and for that reason we end up with this. if this is the cause, is there a way to enforce my lower critical value to be among the generated x values??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat_function` has an argument, `n`, which determines how many values are calculated along the curve. Set this to a high number (say 1000) and the inaccuracy will disappear. For example, with 99 degrees of freedom, the default plot looks like this:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(l.critical - 3, u.critical + 3)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = funcShaded, geom = "area", fill = "#84CA72") +
  stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = n - 1), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = l.critical) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "t values") +
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

But if we add `n = 1000` to `stat_function`, the alignment is perfect:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(l.critical - 3, u.critical + 3)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = funcShaded, geom = "area", fill = "#84CA72", n = 1000) +
  stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = n - 1), linewidth = 1, n = 1000) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = l.critical) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "t values") +
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: That was my first option too. :D

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue you could set the limits in `stat_function` via `xlim` which at the same time allows to get rid of your `funcShaded`:

```r
alpha <- 0.1
n <- 99

l.critical <- qt(alpha, df = n - 1)
u.critical <- -l.critical

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(l.critical - 3, u.critical + 3)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(
    fun = dt,
    args = list(df = n - 1), linewidth = 1
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "t values") +
  stat_function(
    fun = dt, geom = "area", fill = "#84CA72", alpha = 1,
    outline.type = "full", color = "black", xlim = c(l.critical - 3, l.critical),
    args = list(df = n - 1), 
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(y = "") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = l.critical)
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mention, that in future I will modify my code to work for all alternatives, i.e, lower tail, upper tail two tail. I can easily achieve that by modifying the only the  ```funcShaded```. Your solution is although correct for the question here.